# Spring security authorisation by date

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to create a system that grants access to a website depending on the date.

There are 2 roles involved: Admins and Users
and there are 2 dates (date1 < date2)

These are the requirements:

> - You can not login at all before date1
> - **Only** Admins can login after date1
> - After date2 everyone can access the page and no authorisation is required

This is my spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/overview**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/subscribe**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/overview" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthProvider">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

My guess is that I need to write a custom element to replace the intercept-url tag but I have no idea how this can be done.

Comment: No you don't. YOu only need a custom [`UserDetailsChecker`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsChecker.html) which takes into account the date(s) and roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements seem to be mostly about restricting whether people can login (i.e. authenticate) based on the date, but your question also talks about authorisation to URLs based on date. These aren't the same thing and you should probably clarify exactly what you mean. For example, when you say everyone can access the page (which page?) after the second date, do you also mean that no login is required? Or do you mean all authenticated users - i.e. the whole site still requires authentication?

If you are just talking about restricting logins then you can do that most easily by checking the date in a custom `AuthenticationProvider`. Something like:

```
class MyAuthProvider extends SomeStandardAuthenticationProvider {

    public Authentication authenticate (Authentication a) {
        Authentication authenticated = super.authenticate(a);

        Date now = new Date();
        boolean isAdmin = // check authenticated.getAuthorities() for admin role

        if (now.isBefore(date1 || (isAdmin && now.isBefore(date2)) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Too early");
        }

        return authenticated;
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify: After the first date users need to authenticate themselves to access the website. After the second date everyone, also non registered users, can access all content of the website without authentication.

Comment: That still doesn't clear it up completely - you said "Only Admins can login after date1", now you're saying "After the first date users need to authenticate themselves". Do you mean that the only authenticated users you can have are admins? If you don't need authentication after date2, why not just redeploy with security removed after the date is past?

Comment: You got a valid point there to redeploy without security. I didn't give it taught before. Thank you :)